# Advice on refactoring some poor code

Tags: delphi, refactoring, delphi-5

Consider the following

```
constructor TSettlement.Assign( const OldInst : TSettlement; const ResetFsToo: Boolean );
begin
  //inherited
  Create;
  if OldInst = nil then
    exit;

  Self.Acceptancedate := OldInst.Acceptancedate;
  // etc etc
end;
```

and please consider also these invocations elsewhere in the code

```
SettInst.Assign(DisplaySett, False);

DisplaySett := TSettlement.Assign(nil, False);

NewInst := TSettlement.Assign( Displaysett, False );
```

and (perhaps worst of all)

```
  if OldList.Count > 0 then
    for loop := 0 to OldList.Count -1 do  
      Self.Add(TSettlement.Assign(OldList.Data[loop], True));
```

This is leaky code and I object to the use of the method name 'Assign' for a constructor for reasons which I take to be obvious, but I am **not** obliged to fix it.

I want to improve it because I have pride in my work.

I am proposing to change the `Assign` method from a constructor to a procedure and remove the call to `Create()`.  This will require me to change code in many places in the application. Obviously there is risk in doing this.

Before I dive in and get cracking can anyone suggest any alternative approach I should consider?

Are there possible pitfalls I have maybe not thought of that I should be aware of?

Comment: Probably more appropriate for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Either make it a *real* constructor, or make it a *real* function. That code needs to die.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How best to approach some surprising code with minimal intervention](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16041691/how-best-to-approach-some-surprising-code-with-minimal-intervention)

Comment: Word of advice. Always choose to edit closed questions and attempt to get them reopened. Asking a new questions is liable to lead to conflict.

Comment: In other words, please take the new text which you have asked in this question, edit your prior question, replacing it with this text, and then delete this one.

Comment: Speaking of which, just last night I saw someone get banned for doing the same thing.

Comment: @David Heffernan - I was soundly criticised for editing the question previously and appeared to have fallen out completely with the moderator in question; he appeared to accuse me of being rude to another moderator too - hey-ho.  Anyway - you have already suggested an alternative approach - that's most helpful, thanks.

Comment: Refactoring advice: have good tests.

Comment: @Jerry Dodge - thanks, but that option is not available as the prior question has been deleted.

Comment: @David Heffernan - testing yes - the cost of testing is a very compelling argument for just leaving it as-is. Is there anything about the code as it stands that suggests what the coder was trying to achieve? To my eye it is pure gibberish (I can hardly get my head round how many leaks there are) but can you think of any circumstance where it MUST be like this?  I can't.  It needs to die but I need a good clean kill :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That constructor does not necessarily leak. It's plausible that the code actually works. However, it is inpenetrable and leads to calling code whose semantics are hard to discern from the outside. You should refactor.

There's an easy way to refactor. The key is that you break up the two modes of operation into separate functions:

1. A constructor named Create that acts like a normal Delphi constructor. You appear already to have this.
2. A procedure that copies the contents of one instance to another. That could well be named Assign.

So, here's the plan of campaign:

1. Change Assign into a procedure rather than a constructor.
2. Deal with the call to Create that can be found in the current Assign. You need to remove that from Assign, but make sure that everything that it did still happens when Assign runs.
3. Now all constructor mode calls to Assign fail to compile. So we fix them.
4. The ones that passed nil, convert into constructor calls of Create.
5. The other ones need to call the Create constructor and then Assign.

You might want an overloaded Create that receives an existing instance and calls Assign. That could be convenient.

That would leave you able to do all that you do today, but would avoid calling a constructor on an instance which is always a bad idea.

Comment: Also, if there are leaks, it's likely due to calls like those in the OP where `DisplaySett` is assigned to a new object and presumably was previously assigned to an object that is never freed.  It would probably be worth tracking down all instances of `Assign` and ensuring that they are preceded by a `.Free` where needed.  My feeling from reading the OP is that things like `DisplaySett` are likely globals...

Comment: +1 Also for first making a change that will lead to the compiler helping you in finding the code that needs to be addressed.

Comment: @Marjan Yes, well spotted. Order is key here. Make the compiler do the work.

Comment: This is very much the approach in my 'proposal' in the OP - I don't mind so much breaking the code as long as I don't break it silently.  I like the courage and conviction of the answer too - just what I was looking for.

Comment: It's easy to have courage and conviction when suggesting that somebody else refactors their code!  ;-)

Comment: That was going to be my next sentence but I held my tongue :)

Comment: @David Heffernan - I went for it and am reasonably confident with the result.  There was a TStringList member in the TSettlement class which Assign() was assigning using ':='.  This gave me quite some jitters as the software was Access Violating all over the place after the refactor ... Assigning using TStrings.Assign sorted this. Perhaps a lesson there - the less you can trust the code, the harder and the more necessary the refactor becomes.  Thanks for your thoughts.